# Question about polynomial division and division theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

For a certain polynomial, $P(3)=2$ and $P(-1)=-1$. Use this information to deduce the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-3)(x+1)$.

I have tried to create a simultaneous equation with the division theorem, but I'm stuck.
$$
P(x) = Q(x)(x-3) + 2
$$
and
$$
P(x) = Q(x)(x+1) - 1
$$

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried applying the division theorem and create a simultaneous equation, but I'm not sure on how to do that.

Comment: Start by writing down the division of $P(x)$ by $(x-3)(x+1)$, then substitute $x=3$ and $x=-1$ and see what you get. Actually you should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4470681/edit) that into the question, otherwise it's going to get closed for lack of context and own work.

Comment: If I substitute x=3 and x=-1, wouldn't that just give me 2 and -1, as stated in the question? Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: Never mind, it equates the divisor and quotient to 0, and leaves the remainder.

Comment: I still don't understand. I have P(3)=R(3) and P(-1)=R(-1)...

Comment: You divide by a polynomial of degree $2$. What degree will the remainder $R(x)$ have?

Comment: R(x) must have a lower degree than D(x), so it will either have a degree 0 or degree 1.

Comment: Right, so $R(x)=ax+b$ and you know the values at two points, so you can determine $a,b$.

Comment: So P(x)=Q(x)(x-3)(x-1)+ax+b. From here, do I substitute values?

Comment: Please look at [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to typeset math on this site and elsewhere.

Comment: You used $Q(x)$ for both quotients, but they are likely not meant to be the same polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I have solved it!

Comment: See the linked dupe (and it many "Linked" posts) for the standard methods (and many worked examples).